# Communicating multiple containers running golang

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to make to simple micro service using `golang` and `Docker`

I dont understand how to call `add.go` functions from `mainmodule`.

[This post](https://www.callicoder.com/docker-compose-multi-container-orchestration-golang/) does the same, but it uses `github` repo and build it.

I am new to both `golang` and `Docker`, so any suggestion to make this simple app working would be great.

This is my folder structure.

```
- addmodule
    - add.go
    - Dockerfile
- mainmodule
    - main.go
    - Dockerfile

- docker-compose.yml
```

`Dockerfile` in `addmodule`

```
FROM   golang:alpine
RUN apk update
COPY . /go/src
WORKDIR /go/src
RUN go build -o add .
EXPOSE 7070
RUN chmod 755 add
CMD [ "./add" ]
```

`Dockerfile` in `mainmodule`

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk update
COPY . /go/src
WORKDIR /go/src
CMD [ "go","run","main.go" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  addmodule:
    image: addmodule
    build:
      context: ./addmodule
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mainmodule

  mainmodule:
    image : mainmodule
    build:
      context: ./mainmodule
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

My `add.go`

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func add(reswt http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Request came to here")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/add", add)
    http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:7070", nil)

}
```

My `main.go` in `mainmodule`

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("From main package")

    res, err := http.Get("0.0.0.0:7070/add")

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("couldnt send get request")
    }

    log.Println(res)

}
```

When I run `sudo docker-compose up --build` , I just get `couldnt send get request`

PS : Question edited with modified codes according to suggestions given by @MaartenDev

Comment: Please post a comment before down-voting the question, or raise a flag to moderators if question quality is not into standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker compose creates a network by default. The service names can be used to reach the contains in the same network.

```
version: '3'

services:
  addmodule:
    image: addmodule
    build:
      context: ./addmodule
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mainmodule

  mainmodule:
    image : mainmodule
    build:
      context: ./mainmodule
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And the `mainmodule` would be able to reach the add module by connecting to `http://addmodule:<port>` and `addmodule` can reach `mainmodule` by: `http://mainmodule`

This assumes these are http services. Any other transport will work because the `addmodule` and `mainmodule` are made available using DNS.

When using custom ports ensure that the ports are exposed in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM   golang:alpine
RUN apk update
COPY . /go/src
WORKDIR /go/src

EXPOSE 7070
```

Your http should bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. This ensures that the service is reachable from outside the container:

```
http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:7070", nil)
```

The main code should use the following:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("From main package")

    res, err := http.Get("http://addmodule:7070/add")  // The mistake I made after a long chat. forgot http://

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("couldnt send get request")
    }

    log.Println(res)

}
```

Read more about the default network: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I will have to run `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` similar thing in `addmodule` and handle that request?

Comment: Yes, `HTTP` is the easiest way to setup communication between containers @Sachith

Comment: In my `mainmodule` I use `http.Get("http://addmodule:7070")`, and in `addmoudle` I have `http.ListenAndServe("http://addmodule:7070", nil)`, but it says can not send request.

Comment: You will need to expose the ports in your dockerfile using `EXPOSE 7070`

Comment: still no luck, I have updated the question with latest changed codes.

Comment: I updated the answer, the customer(`mainmodule`) should use the DNS address, the producer(`addmodule`) should use `0.0.0.0`. @Sachith

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198447/discussion-between-maartendev-and-sachith).