# How to fix 502 Bad Gateway error while using nginx with Docker and Reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I am developing an application that uses:

- Reactjs + Nginx as frontend
- Nodejs as backend

The two applications exchange information via an API via `localhost` (it's working when I test things separately with `node index.js` and `yarn start`).

I'm trying to create a `docker-compose` to run the application as a whole, but I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error when trying to access `localhost:4000`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
  
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: "./backend"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./backend:/app

  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
```

This is my project tree:

```
My-Project
 ┣ backend
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┣ .dockerignore
 ┃ ┣ Dockerfile
 ┃ ┣ index.js
 ┃ ┣ package-lock.json
 ┃ ┗ package.json
 ┣ frontend
 ┃ ┣ build
 ┃ ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┣ public
 ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ .dockerignore
 ┃ ┣ Dockerfile
 ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┗ yarn.lock
 ┣ nginx
 ┃ ┣ default.conf
 ┃ ┗ Dockerfile
 ┗ docker-compose.yml
```

This is my nginx `default.conf`:

```
upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
    server backend:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /backend {
        rewrite /backend/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

I'm testing the application with the command `docker-compose up --build` and oppening the browser in the path `localhost:4000`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: in nginx.conf you use `frontend` and `backend` for upstream names, but those are also service names. It would be better to make a distinction. Also make sure the frontend listens on 0.0.0.0:3000 and not only on the local interface 127.0.0.1:3000. You can test this by opening a shell in the nginx container and try to curl http://frontend:3000

Comment: Will this be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646760/communicating-multiple-containers-running-golang

Comment: the docker contianer `nginx` `frontend` `backend` should in same network, the example of docker network  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks-top-level-element

Comment: What is actually running on `port 4000` ? I can't see anything related to it in your code